# Possible jQuery conflict when using bgStretcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming

I have setup a test html page to play with bgStretcher before adding it to a custom Wordpress theme. It works fine when I use the jQuery version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

on , but it stops working when I use the version included in Wordpress:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pebbl.es/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1"></script>
```

The only difference I've seen between the two files is that the WP version prevents jQuery conflicts at the end, calling noConflict().

The page (html below) loads the first image, but then the console outputs an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
(anonymous function)**

The live version is on: http://pebbl.es/test/test .Any ideas on how to fix this? I can see it is a conflict error, but I can't see where/how to fix it? Many thanks.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pebbl.es/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bgstretcher.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bgstretcher.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery('body').bgStretcher({
            images: ['Rochy_Coleccion1.jpg', 'Rochy_Coleccion2.jpg'], imageWidth: 1024, imageHeight: 748
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace your jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

add this between the two script tags:

```
var $my_jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

after this, you have your 1.6.1 jQuery in no conflict mode.
you will have to call it using your variable name after this, e.g. `$my_jq('#content')`

**UPDATE**

this might not work, I see you are not loading 2 different jQuerys, your problem occurs when trying to use bgstretcher with an jQuery that is already in noConflict mode.

I am not a wordpress expert, but you might just change the wordpress jQuery to use your variable name. You can set jQuery in noConflict mode with or without namespacing it to a variable and it looks like your wordpress JQ does it without.
Or you can first load your own jQuery, namespace it and then use this for bgstretch.
The problem is that the noConflict call "frees" the $ variable again for use with different frameworks that also want to make use of it, so your bgstretch gets an error when trying to call $.

Or just try to remove the noConflict completly and see if it has any effect on your wordpress installation (it should not, I guess it is just for the purpose of giving WP users the ability to use different JS frameworks as well).

Hope you work it out.

Comment: There is already a call to noConflict() at the end of the Wordpress' included jQuery. I have tried your suggestion, without success:

Comment: <html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pebbl.es/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bgstretcher.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bgstretcher.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
   var $my_jq = jQuery.noConflict();
   $my_jq(document).ready(function(){
        $my_jq('body').bgStretcher({
            images: ['Rochy_Coleccion1.jpg', 'Rochy_Coleccion2.jpg'], imageWidth: 1024, imageHeight: 748
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: after rereading your question and looking to your live site i updated my answer.

Comment: The solution was changing the background stretching js from bgStretcher to Supersized. BgStretcher does not play nicely sharing jQuery with Wordpress: the first slide on a slideshow loaded, but it got stuck on the second slide. Supersized can share the same jQuery as WP, and it can handle noConflict well: jQuery(function($) {$.supersized( ...etc. Thanks!